# Javascript missing argument

Tags: javascript

```
create_anchor.setAttribute("onclick",
   "getModelData("+model.model_id.toString()+",
   "+model.model_name.toString +")");
```

it showing error while i'm passing another parameter to that function,the error is "missing ) after argument list"

> [Break on this error] 
>   the ouput is like this 
>   getModelData(7,xxxx - xxxx series(H))

Answer (score 2):

```
create_anchor.setAttribute("onclick","getModelData("+model.model_id.toString()+",'"+model.model_name.toString +"')");
```

Your mode.model_name.toString should be enclosed in quotes

Comment: well seems logical, also don't forget on `'"+model.model_id.toString()+"'`

Comment: u forgot to specify the toString() function, after i had used this but it shows up other error JSON.parse
this is line where error is highlighting 
var myJSONObject = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);